# Native windows Linux

Tags: linux, windows, mingw, portable-executable

I know about several projects for cross compiling between linux and Windows.

The [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) project is great for running windows application inside Linux.

[andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/reqs.php) is a linux running inside Windows.

My question is, can we compile a complete linux OS with a Windows compiler (like mingw32, visual studio , ...) in order to get a linux system which is fully compatible with the Windows PE executable format ?

Comment: mingw32 is a minimalist development environment for windows, Visual Studio is an IDE. They are not compilers.

Comment: Linux natively supports ELF, a.out and COFF as object file format. I don't think it supports PE.

Comment: @lulyon mingw32 includes a version of the GCC compiler which generates PE files. Microsoft visual studio comes with its own compiler.  In both these cases it is common for people to refer to the two as compilers because they both contain a compiler.  The meaning of either of these when referenced as a compiler is never ambiguous or unclear.

Answer (score 4):

As wine demonstrates, the PE format isn't really the problem with compatibility.

PE only defines how the program is pieced together at load time.  Under windows, RUNDLL interprets it, loads all the program sections to memory, loads all the supporting dlls to memory and patches up the function pointers so that there is a program sitting in memory ready to go. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx for more details. *Its a good read!*)

There is little stopping you writing a kernel module to do all of this.  With the details in the page linked above it may not be to hard and someone may already have done it.

The real issue is the fundamentals of the operating system.  Even if linux could load a PE, there would be problems around the fundamental difference in file names (\ or /) as well as the permissions model which is different and the windows registry which doesn't exist under linux.  That's before you get into the different windowing model for GUIs.

Therefore the task of getting a windows program to run under linux is less about the program loader and much more about emulating all of the windows DLLs under Linux.  As i understand it, this is the main heart of wine.

Comment: +1 You make the whole question quite clear. Program loader, Windows DLL emulating under Linux, sounds like what Cygwin do.

Comment: You can let WINE run `.exe` files using `bin_fmt`. It will load win32 executables transparently if set up correctly, which is quite cool.

Comment: @couling, Yes. You are right about the requested modification of the linux source code in order to take into account the Windows specifities like file system, registry, device drivers, etc.But i think that these modification are a not very hard to be acheived for the linux community. The "nice" idea is to make a Linux "clone" which is 100% Windows compatible.

Comment: replacing / with \\ could be done using a #DEFINE. The linux /etc emulates nearly the registry. It is not necessary to re-designe linux to acheive them. As you said, what is needed is a set of DLLs to provide a Windows compatible layer above a linux kernel compiled with the PE format.